# jQuery .prop() function not working (.prop() vs .attr())

Tags: jquery, html

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/ripter/jquery.rating) for jQuery.

The plugin tries to create an anchor (`<a>`) tag, with a `value=` attribute. However, it does not create the tag with any such attribute in my browser. Is this a `jQuery` problem? Or an HTML problem? I'm not sure why it seems to be working for so many others, but not for me.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$("<a/>").prop({
      className: "ui-rating-star ui-rating-empty",
      title: $(this).text(),   // perserve the option text as a title.
      value: this.value        // perserve the value.
}).appendTo(elm);
```

This is supposed to create the following element:

```
<a class=​"ui-rating-star ui-rating-empty" title=​"1 Star">​</a>​
```

I am using jQuery v1.9.1, if that matters.

Comment: As an aside, why are you setting a `value` on an anchor element anyway?

Comment: well I didn't write the code, I am debugging the broken script from the github URL

Comment: OK, fair enough. Note that properties and attributes aren't the same thing. If you try to retrieve the _property_ after it is set does it work? `$("a.ui-rating-star").prop("value")`? (or whatever selector gets the new element)

Comment: [Prop vs Attr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: @nnnnnn no, because it would be an attr and not a prop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.prop` only sets properties, not attributes. If an attribute is created, the browser did it not jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thank you, I didnt' even notice. Though this wasn't my code to begin with, I am now using attr and it works fine.

Comment: +1 When i tried .prop() i was expecting it not to put the attributes but it created the element with attributes so i was wondering.. SO its the Browser....